# Problem putting affiliations in footnote using authblk

Tags: footnotes, titles, authblk

I want to use `authblk` package for a better affiliation formatting, but when I use this package affiliations don't go to the footnote as expected.
This is how I used that package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}

\title{My title\\in two lines}

\author[1]{A}
\affil[1]{Affil A \texttt{myemail@somewhere.world}}

\author[2]{B}
\affil[2]{Affil B}

\author[3]{C}
\affil[3]{Affil C}


\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
a very nice abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{saying hello}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

What should I do?

Update: I just forgot to put `\maketitle`. The problem still persists after adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\affil` macro of the `authblk` package is an extension to LaTeX's `\author` command. Like `\author` (and `\title` and `\date`), it only records some data, but doesn't typeset anything. For typesetting, one must add `\maketitle` immediately after `\begin{document}`. (Sorry if this is old news to you, but your example doesn't include `\maketitle`, and the `authblk` documentation doesn't mention it, too.)

EDIT: In response to your comment: Simply use `\and` and `\thanks`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{My title\\in two lines}

\author{%
A\thanks{Affil A \texttt{myemail@somewhere.world}}%
\and
B\thanks{Affil B}%
\and
C\thanks{Affil C}%
}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
A very nice abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Saying hello}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have put that `\maketitle` after `\begin{document}' in the original work indeed. I update my original question for that.

Comment: If you want "real" footnotes (positioned at the bottom of the page), `authblk` most likely is not the package for you. Would a solution involving `\thanks` be acceptable?

Comment: Of course. It is surprising that `authblk` does not support real footnotes. By the way I want to achieve something like [this](http://physbam.stanford.edu/~fedkiw/papers/stanford2003-10.pdf).